# How to run Threads at the same time and stop one of them without stopping other Thread?

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, datetime, multiprocessing

I'm developing a reminder app. I'm asking this question for the 4th time. My issue is, I have 2 `Threads`. I'm using this `Threads` as reminders.

When the reminder date comes, the `Thread` stops.

Here's an example:

```
import datetime
from threading import Thread

# Current date & time: 12:30, 8/21/2020
current = datetime.datetime.now()

# First reminder: 12:35, 8/21/2020 
a = datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 21, 12, 35)

# Second reminder: 12:40, 8/21/2020
b = datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 21, 12, 40)
```

Let's say I created 2 `Threads`. One `Thread` is waiting for `a` and the other one is waiting for `b`.

Everything is working nicely. Those `Threads` will wait until the reminder date comes. And then they will stop automatically using flag.

BUT when I attempt to stop `Thread` `a`, program stops `Thread` `b` too.

How to prevent this? Here's my full code:

```
import threading
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

class Reminder:

    # Target function
    def createThread(self, check):

        # Specific date (10 secs later from current date)
        b = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds = 10)

        # Set flag (in this case it's 'e')
        global e
        e = check  # gets value from parameter

        while True:

            # Current time
            a = datetime.now()
            
            # If user wants to stop Thread and e equals True, break
            if e == True:
                print("** REMINDER STOPPED ** -> Stopped.\n")
                break

            # If current time and set time equals, break
            else:
                if a >= b:
                    print("** REMINDER NOTIFICATION ** -> Worked.")
                    break

    def exec(self):

        # Global Thread name
        global t

        # Set thread, sleep 1 seconds and stop the thread
        t = threading.Thread(target = self.createThread, args = [False])

        # Start thread
        t.start()

        # Wait
        time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):

        global e
        e = True  # Stop thread


# This while statement checks program is still running
while True:
    
    # Input
    se = input("\nYup?")
    print(se)

    # Call class
    r = Reminder()

    # If input equals 'e', run the Thread
    if se == 'e':
        r.exec()

    # If input equals 'd', stop the Thread
    if se == 'd':
        r.stop()
```

**I want to set `Threads` by their name and delete them by their name.**

**Such as when I type `delete a`, program stops `Thread a`, but `Thread b` should be keep running.**

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set flag to stop a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473488/how-to-set-flag-to-stop-a-thread)

Comment: No, that man helped me to create and stop every Thread that I created. I want to delete Threads by giving them a name. If I have a and b Threads and I want to stop a Thread, b should be keep running. But that man's answer doesn't help me about this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of one shared flag for all threads, you need a flag per thread.

The simplest way to do that is to have set or dict containing the thread objects or their thread_ids.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I apologize, but I did not understand how to do it. If you don't mind, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve and stop threads by name, a dictionary is likely your best bet. You can spin up a thread and associate to a string.

```py
spool = dict()

# add new thread
spool["first"] = threading.Thread(target = self.createThread, args = [False])

spool["first"].start()

# retrieve and stop thread
thread = spool["first"]
thread.join()
```

That being said, it would likely be both simpler and more efficient to simply store an ordered list of the reminders, and have a single thread iterating over them until one matches the current time or whatever reminder conditional you want to have.

```py
class Reminder:
    def __init__(self, time, msg):
        self.time = time
        self.msg = msg

def daemon(reminders):
    while True:
        for reminder in reminders:
            if reminder.time <= datetime.now:
                # print message or other actions ...

reminders = list[]

d = threading.Thread(target = daemon, args = [reminders])

# add more reminders and other program actions
```

You could also simply use the [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to execute a function after a give number of seconds. See the below example modified from the docs:

```py
def hello():
    print("hello, world")

year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
t = Timer(year, hello)
t.start()  # after 1 year, "hello, world" will be printed
```

Comment: threading.Timer raises 'OverflowError: timeout value is too large' error. And I apologize, but I did not understand how to do it this stuff using dict. Could you please explain a little more what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: What value is causing the OverflowError? As far as I can tell it will go up to at least 999999999 which is 31.7 years. Unless you have some really specific use case, I can't imagine anyone setting plans that far ahead

Comment: Python dictionaries are for at intents and purposes a hashmap. They store key value pairs, and you use the key value to access and mutate the value in the dictionary. Here is a link to a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: If I type a number bigger than 4294967 (which is 49.71 days), it gives me OverflowError. I'm not sure why you are not getting error when you type 999999999. By the way, my OS is Windows 8.1 32-bit.

Comment: I would like to send you my original code to fix the error. Please contact me on Instagram: ugurokuduro

Comment: Oh, thats likely the cause. There is a fundamental difference between 32 and 64 bit systems which change the default and handle able size of an integer. On a 32 bit system, it'll max out around (2^32) / 2 - 1 for signed integers, while a 64 maxes out around (2^64) / 2 - 1

Comment: This is why I'm using while loop instead of threading.Timer. To stop Thread, I'm using flags. But I guess I need flags for each Thread. But I couldn't solve the issue. :/

Comment: Your best bet is to use the dictionary method then

Comment: I understood how to set a name to thread, but how to stop the Thread before the reminder time comes? In your example, you're not starting the Thread but you're using join() function to stop Thread.

Comment: Woops, I added the start line, sorry about that! You access the thread object by indexing the dictionary with the thread name, and call `join` on the retrieved object. If you are still confused by this, open a new question so we can avoid making this comment thread much longer

Comment: You should be opening new questions we can keep comment threads short, but check that the end condition is being met and that you are breaking out of the while loop